# Catch std exception and System Exception in mixed C++

Tags: c++, exception, clr

What is the correct way to catch std and System exception in mixed code C++ applications?

like this?

```
try
{
    // using pure C++ and managed components
}
catch(std::exception exp)
{
}
catch(System::Exception sexp)
{
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Catch exceptions by reference.  A hard requirement for managed exception, optional for native C++ exceptions but still a good idea.  It is just spelled differently:

```
try {
    // stuff
}
catch (std::exception& ex) {
}
catch (System::Exception^ ex) {
}
```

Catch-them-all exception handling is however almost never a good idea.

Answer (score 2):

Catch them by reference to avoid slicing for derived exceptions of `std::exception`:

```
catch (std::exception &exp)
```

This way you can catch all derived exceptions properly. (Polymorphism)

Comment: Good practice or all native exceptions! Only when a library specifically says you must catch exceptions by pointer, then you **must** catch by pointer.

Comment: @Henno: Oh god, there are libraries that do that? That's horrible. In what way is their library broken such that this is needed?

Comment: No! I did mean it in another way: When **YOU** are using a nativ library of someone else, then...

Answer (score 2):

Please read [this](https://blogs.msdn.com/b/liviuc/archive/2009/10/13/.net-interop-and-exception-handling-in-mixed-applications.aspx?Redirected=true) MS-Blog-Post.
Specifically where it says: "Generally speaking, it is easier to deal with native errors/exceptions in managed code that the other way round..."
Managed exceptions reach the native part in the form of SEH-Exceptions with reduced information compared to managed ecxeptions.

So, no, your code snippet is not correct.